# Checking if a random number already exists VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I have written code which generates a random number between 1-9.

I now want to add to this and generate a random number but generate a new number if that number has already been used before.

```
Sub main()
 Dim max,min
max=9
min=1
Randomize
MsgBox(Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
```

// Random number between 1-9 is generated

I had tried to implement a loop but i'm unsure of how it would work as i would need to keep the number generated in memory

```
 If Int =  random
    Msgbox("Already in use")
End If

If Int = not random Then
    Msgbox("Can be used")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When all the available numbers in range are retrieved and you ask for another one, what should happen?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to keep track of which random numbers have already been chosen.  You could handle this any number of different ways (eg, with an array, hash-table/dictionary, numeric bit mask, etc.)

The solution I present below is similar to a numeric bit mask, but uses a string.  Starting at all zeros (eg, "0000"), each indexable position in the string gets populated with a one (1) until the string becomes all ones (eg, "1111").  While potentially oversimplified -- since it assumes your min will always be one (1) -- it should get you started.

```
Dim min : min=1
Dim max : max=9
Dim result : result = ""
Dim r, s: s = String(max, "0")

Randomize

Do
    r = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
    If "0" = Mid(s, r, 1) Then
        WScript.Echo "Can be used: " & r
        result = result & ":" & r
        s = Left(s, r-1) & "1" & Right(s, max-r)
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Already in use: " & r
    End If
Loop Until String(max, "1") = s

WScript.Echo "Result" & result
```

Sample output:

```
Can be used: 4
Can be used: 5
Can be used: 9
Can be used: 3
Already in use: 3
Can be used: 1
Can be used: 8
Can be used: 6
Already in use: 6
Can be used: 7
Already in use: 8
Already in use: 4
Already in use: 3
Already in use: 1
Already in use: 6
Can be used: 2
Result:4:5:9:3:1:8:6:7:2
```

Hope this helps.